# CNN for image to feature vector

Tags: image, pytorch, data-analysis, conv-neural-network

I have a rather simple question, but I cannot wrap my head around this. You need to correct me in the case that I have understood something wrong!!! Typically, CNNs are used for image classification, where the FC layers are used to output the probability per given class.

**I want actually something else:**
Can I train a CNN to output a feature vector? One example would be: Input==Image; Output==Color histogram with 3 channels (RGB) and every channel value is the number of red, green, blue pixels.
(I actually want to learn other image feature descriptors for special images, but that should then work analogous).

*Pointers, Links and Tutorials* (esp. **code** that I can modify for my purposes) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

the output of a CNN is a feature vector,it means the input is an image and you'd get a feature vector of that image as an output. That feature vector has been computed by using a mask that apply on that image. Those feature vector is been used for classification.
it's up to you that use the output for classification or anything else.
this link might help you more.
http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/

Comment: You need to help me with my naive understanding here: I simply don't have classes, but I want to compute one or multiple numeric scores.

Comment: your dataset is ready? it is based on what you want? I mean you need to have train data with some images and some score for each image, then you use them for train the neural network, then you can get those score for test images. there is some function like predict. after training when your model is ready, you can use that model to predict the new images, look for some function like "predict"

Comment: for example look at here: I built a model with training a neural network with my training data. then I use that model to predict the test data: 'preds = model.predict_classes(test)' . its output isn't a class, the output is a numeric vector that I can decode that as I want and make it a word or an score .